# Looking for a Azure Service Bus Relayed example that does not use WCF

Tags: c#, azure, servicebus, azure-servicebusrelay

I'm trying to get my head around Azure Web Service Relay, but I'm looking for a .NET (C#) example that does NOT use WCF - both on the sender and receiver side.
Does anyone have any good suggestions for an Azure rookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that currently Service Bus Relay can only expose services developed in WCF. 
[This](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-relay/) brief 'how to' page specifically mentions WCF and I do not think it's an accident (my bold)-

> The Service Bus relay facilitates this by enabling you to securely
>   expose **Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)** services that reside
>   within a corporate enterprise network to the public cloud...

Consuming services without WCF is, of course, possible even today, depending on which binding you use and the client capabilities, but a lot of the logic of the relay service 'negotiation' is implemented over WCF.

I would imagine that, with enough effort, it would be possible to take it out of WCF, but I don't think Microsoft provides anything like that and I haven't seen any attempts so far.